# Exclude enum item when using key in Enum

Tags: typescript

I have a enum like this (just a little bit bigger):

```
export enum MyTypeEnum {
    one = 'one',
    two = 'two',
    three = 'three',
    four = 'four'
}
```

I use it to define types that need to have those keys in this way:

```
export type MyTypeKeyFunctionValue = { [key in MyTypeEnum ]?: Function };
export type MyTypeKeyStringValue = { [key in MyTypeEnum ]?: string };
```

So in my class I can do something like:

```
private memberWithFunctions: MyTypeKeyFunctionValue;
```

Now, I have a special situation when some member needs to have all the keys in `MyTypeEnum` BUT one (lets say `two`) and I do not know how to define a type that excludes that key but keeps all the other keys.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the `Exclude` conditional type to remove a member from the `enum`

```
export type MyTypeKeyStringValue = { 
    [key in Exclude<MyTypeEnum, MyTypeEnum.two> ]?: string
 };
```

Comment: When I declare `memberWithFunctions: MyTypeKeyStringValue ` and use it in this way: `this.memberWithFunctions[someEnumValue]` Typescript says : *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'MyTypeKeyStringValue ' has no index signature. [7017]*

Comment: @distante since some enum members cant be keys you need to guard against them. First access causes an error second one does not:  
`declare let a: MyTypeKeyStringValue;

declare let x: MyTypeEnum;
let r0 = a[x]
if (x !== MyTypeEnum.two) {
  let r = a[x]
}`

Comment: I see! I would never arrive to that conclusion from that Error. Thank you @titian-cernicova-dragomir . Maybe you should add this to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Omit` type to skip a property.

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

Usage:

```
const foo: Omit<MyTypeKeyFunctionValue, MyTypeEnum.two> = {
  /* ... */
}
```